# rmarkdown render fails to create pdf files inside a loop

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, render

Hello everybody outhere.
I am having an issue which I do not understand. I am generating a pdf file which is a repport from a database and creates a table and two plots. Each time I run it by hand it works. But, if I go to the database through a loop to create the pdf files, it only creates one file each 2 files (one file ok, the next is an empty pdf, the next ok, the next empty, and so on). At the end, I finally end up doing something very ugly like this:

```
    rmarkdown::render("~/projects/myFile.Rmd",
                    "pdf_document"
                    ,output_dir = "~/projects/PDFALL"
                    , output_file = namefile
                    , envir = new.env()
                    , clean = FALSE)
  fs<-file.size(paste("~/projects/PDFALL/",namefile,sep=""))
  if(fs<50*1024){
  rmarkdown::render("~/projects/myFile.Rmd",
                    "pdf_document"
                    ,output_dir = "~/projects/PDFALL"
                    , output_file = namefile
                    , envir = new.env()
                    , clean = FALSE)}
```

This way, it works for every file, but this is just a walkaround. Something is not working with timing inside the compiling proccess file. I have had used Sys.sleep() or something like that and nothing. The .tex file for the right pdf has a size of around 8Kb, while the empty ones, only 2.4Kb.

What is happenning ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Nothing to say? Please.  :..(